# How can you download all wheels from pypi for a specific version of project

Tags: python, pip, pypi

I have tried to use `pip download` for downloading wheels but the problem was that I needed to download all platform wheels that means:

- I am using Windows 10
- The package I want is having wheels built for Linux, OS X, Windows
- I want to download all platform wheels but only for a specific version of project

For example:
I want to download `pygame==2.0.0` with wheels for all platforms so I can later use them. Also I want to download All dependenies of it recursively like that.

**EDIT**

I just found the json api and works great with pypi, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can scrape all links on the ["Download files" tab of *pygame 2.0.0*](https://pypi.org/project/pygame/2.0.0/#files).
- Or you can use the [JSON api endpoint for *pygame 2.0.0*](https://pypi.org/pypi/pygame/2.0.0/json). Look for the `urls` list on the return JSON object. [[doc](https://warehouse.pypa.io/api-reference/json.html)]
- There are probably tools, libraries that can help with that.

---

> Also I want to download All dependenies of it recursively like that.

In general, this is quite a different story. You would need to know in advance the details of each platform you are targeting: operating system, python implementation, python interpreter version, CPU bitness. And maybe you could build commands such as:

```
python -m pip download pygame==2.0.0 --only-binary=:all: --platform win32 --python-version 37
```

But unless I am mistaken (I did not check thoroughly), it seems to me like *pygame* does not have dependencies.

Comment: thanks, but i know that i am not using pygame. i just thought it might be a good example. Also for now i think that json api is the best because i can parse through it easily